# How to read request body in HandlerInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have Spring Boot and I need to log user action in DB, so I wrote HandlerInterceptor:

```
@Component
public class LogInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
@Autovired
private LogUserActionService logUserActionService;
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) 
throws IOException {
    String userName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    String url = request.getRequestURI();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString() != null ? request.getQueryString() : "";
    String body = "POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) ? new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())) : queryString;
    logUserActionService.logUserAction(userName, url, body);
    return true;
}
}
```

But according to this answer [Get RequestBody and ResponseBody at HandlerInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193380/get-requestbody-and-responsebody-at-handlerinterceptor) "RequestBody can be read only once", so as I understand I read input stream and then Spring tries to do same, but stream has been read already and I'm getting an error: "Required request body is missing ..."

So I tried different ways to make buffered input stream i.e.:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpServletRequest.getInputStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))
```

Or

```
InputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream());
```

But nothing helped
Also I tried to use

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserActionRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {
```

But it has only body, no request info like URL or Request parameters
Also tried to use Filters, but result same.

So I need a good way to get information from request like user, URL, parameters, body (if present) and write it to DB.

Comment: Please check this one using filter, it worked for me. https://gist.github.com/int128/e47217bebdb4c402b2ffa7cc199307ba

Comment: Harshit, there is no body reading in your example, only URL etc.

Comment: Yes it has, check ```logRequestBody``` method.

Comment: Harshit, are you sure this code works? Cause I sent JSON body and wrote next code according to your example: new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request).getContentAsByteArray(); and it returned empty byte array, but my controller got my DTO entity as expected. So I've got body, but method getContentAsByteArray returned nothing.

Answer (score 7):

To log HTTP Request & Response, you can use `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter` and `ResponseBodyAdvice`. here, it is using in my way.

CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {

        // here you can full log httpServletRequest and body.

        return super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }
}
```

CustomResponseBodyAdviceAdapter.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseBodyAdviceAdapter implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        if (serverHttpRequest instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest && serverHttpResponse instanceof ServletServerHttpResponse) {

            // here you can full log httpServletRequest and body.
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

Above `AdviceAdapter` cannot handle the `GET` request. So, you can use `HandlerInterceptor`.

CustomWebConfigurerAdapter.java

```
@Component
public class CustomWebConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Autowired
   private CustomLogInterceptor httpServiceInterceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(httpServiceInterceptor);
   }
}
```

CustomLogInterceptor.java

```
@Component
public class CustomLogInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        if (DispatcherType.REQUEST.name().equals(request.getDispatcherType().name()) && request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.name())) {

            // here you can full log httpServletRequest and body for GET Request.

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here you can reference full source code in my git.

[springboot-http-request-response-loging-with-json-logger](https://github.com/zawthanoo/mutu-sprest-logging)

+Feature => It is already have Integration with **ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana)**

Comment: Have you read my question? I said that I tried it 'but it has only body, no request info like URL or Request parameters'. Is there any way to get URL and query parameters using RequestBodyAdviceAdapter? May be I son't see something, but there is no request parameter in RequestBodyAdviceAdapter methods. If you show me how to get URL and request parameters in RequestBodyAdviceAdapter it would be great!

Comment: And about Interseptor, I said if I read body in interceptor I'll get an Error, and you suggest me to use CustomLogInterceptor, why?? Did you read my question? How to ready body there?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Filter` to log request body.

```
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, res);
        } finally {
            logRequestBody(wrappedRequest);
        }
    }

    private static void logRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {

        byte[] buf = request.getContentAsByteArray();
        if (buf.length > 0) {
            try {
                String requestBody = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, request.getCharacterEncoding());
                System.out.println(requestBody);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error in reading request body");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing to note here is that you have to pass object of `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` in filter chain otherwise you won't get request content in it.

In above example, if you use `chain.doFilter(req, res)` or `chain.doFilter(request, res)` then you won't get request body in `wrappedRequest` object.

Comment: Work great, I didn't though about it, that's solution witch I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: This does work but only when you log after `chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, res)` call. The reason is because `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` fills out the cache only when InputStream is read. If you want to log request payload before handling the request, then you'd need to extend `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` with your own wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Request Body data using **RequestBodyAdviceAdapter** for POST/PUT requests. You can use **HandlerInterceptorAdapter** for GET calls. Here's a working example -
https://frandorado.github.io/spring/2018/11/15/log-request-response-with-body-spring.html

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter
{

@Autowired
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter.class);

private static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = ISO_8859_1;


@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, 
                        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass)
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage,
                            MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) 
{
    Instant startTime = Instant.now();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    
    stringBuilder.append("REQUEST call Starts :: Start Time : %s ").append(startTime);

    try
    {
        logRequest(httpServletRequest, body);

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        LOGGER.info("Exception getting the Request Body into the Log: {}" + e.getMessage());
    }
    

public void logRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Object body) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Map<String, String> parameters = buildParametersMap(httpServletRequest);
    
    
    stringBuilder.append("REQUEST ");
    stringBuilder.append("method=[").append(httpServletRequest.getMethod()).append("] ");
    stringBuilder.append("path=[").append(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()).append("] ");
    stringBuilder.append("headers=[").append(buildHeadersMap(httpServletRequest)).append("] ");
    
    if (!parameters.isEmpty())
    {
        stringBuilder.append("parameters=[").append(parameters).append("] ");
    }
    
    if (body != null)
    {
        stringBuilder.append("body=[" + body + "]");
    }

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    String jsonInString = null;
    try 
    {
        jsonInString = objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(body);
    } 
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
    {
        throw new RestApiException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
    
    stringBuilder.append("REQUEST Body = [").append(jsonInString).append("] ");
    
    LOGGER.info("BODY DATA >>>> " + jsonInString);
    LOGGER.info("Body - : {}" + stringBuilder);
}



private Map<String, String> buildParametersMap(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
{
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = httpServletRequest.getParameterNames();
    
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String key = parameterNames.nextElement();
        String value = httpServletRequest.getParameter(key);
        resultMap.put(key, value);
    }
    
    return resultMap;
}

private Map<String, String> buildHeadersMap(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        String key = headerNames.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    
    return map;
}
}
```

I have used ObjectMapper here because I need the body response as raw JSON object, but the **afterBodyRead()** is invoked after the body is transformed to Java Object.

Comment: Please post minimal example. it will be more helpful for asker.

Comment: @Daniel.Wang Thanks for the suggestion. Added the working code for the same.

Answer (score -2):

I found this solved my problem for copying the request buffer for application/json content types. It also shows how to extend the wrapper as the comments to Harshit solution mentions.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-log-the-request-body-in-a-spring-boot-application-10083b70c66

The important pieces are that you need a filter to pass along the new request to the server.

```java
@Component
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if (Arrays.asList("POST", "PUT").contains(httpRequest.getMethod())) {
            CustomHttpRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new CustomHttpRequestWrapper(httpRequest);
            requestWrapper.setAttribute("input", requestWrapper.getBodyInStringFormat());
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

The logger requires a custom wrapper, and the one spring boot provides seems to be insufficient for application/json type messages.

```java
public class CustomHttpRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public String getBodyInStringFormat() {
        return bodyInStringFormat;
    }

    private final String bodyInStringFormat;

    public CustomHttpRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        bodyInStringFormat = readInputStreamInStringFormat(request.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(request.getCharacterEncoding()));
    }

    private String readInputStreamInStringFormat(InputStream stream, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        return getString(stream, charset);
    }

    static String getString(InputStream stream, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        final int MAX_BODY_SIZE = 1024;
        final StringBuilder bodyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (!stream.markSupported()) {
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        }

        stream.mark(MAX_BODY_SIZE + 1);
        final byte[] entity = new byte[MAX_BODY_SIZE + 1];
        final int bytesRead = stream.read(entity);

        if (bytesRead != -1) {
            bodyStringBuilder.append(new String(entity, 0, Math.min(bytesRead, MAX_BODY_SIZE), charset));
            if (bytesRead > MAX_BODY_SIZE) {
                bodyStringBuilder.append("...");
            }
        }
        stream.reset();

        return bodyStringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader()  {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream ()  {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bodyInStringFormat.getBytes());

        return new ServletInputStream() {
            private boolean finished = false;

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                return finished;
            }

            @Override
            public int available()  {
                return byteArrayInputStream.available();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                super.close();
                byteArrayInputStream.close();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            public int read ()  {
                int data = byteArrayInputStream.read();
                if (data == -1) {
                    finished = true;
                }
                return data;
            }
        };
    }
}
```