# Spring Access @RequestBody object outside Controller Method

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a component that should be able to access the @RequestBody object that is sent  within a request and check if it’s of a certain type.

Is there a way to do this, without deserializing the object again and without manually saving the @RequestBody somewhere when the controller method (where the @RequestBody parameter is declared) is called?

I’d like a solution that works independently of the rest controller and without modifying it’s methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a class that extends `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68083597/1015482), solves the problem.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
                                Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }

}
```

The method `supports` should return true if the Class should be able to handle the request. And inside `afterBodyRead` you can access the object and process it.