# spring boot security authentication to verify body contents

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I want to Authenticate one of the post request body key-value pair, but I want to do the same with the help of a Interceptor/Filter. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot call `response.sendError(..) after `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` is called. Because the latter call writes the response to outputstream and hence the error. The second solution I posted seems to be working locally for me.

Comment: Get the request body using `req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))` And try.

Comment: it shows getReader() has already being called for this request

Comment: Refer this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times

Comment: Refer this :  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times

Comment: Yup, I already referred that. Have mentioned in the comments above

Comment: But is it ok/safe to do so to solve the issue?

Comment: That's the ideal way to read the request body more than once. Now in your case, you want to read the requestBody(which as I observe is not recommended) within filter to take some action and then proceed to other filter(Default spring filters). Hence you need to cache the requestBody the first time you read and then pass it on to further filters.

Comment: Read request body more than once like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804205/how-can-i-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-spring-handlermethodargumentresol

Comment: I feel that should solve the issue but then it's definitely not recommend, but it seems there's no way around.

Comment: From the documentation of HandlerInterceptor - `As a basic guideline, fine-grained handler-related preprocessing tasks are candidates for HandlerInterceptor implementations, especially factored-out common handler code and authorization checks. On the other hand, a Filter is well-suited for request content and view content handling, like multipart forms and GZIP compression. This typically shows when one needs to map the filter to certain content types (e.g. images), or to all requests.`

Comment: Can you share the link ? so should I use filters or Handler Interceptor for my task?

Comment: Refer this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html. You should try to do Auth by taking the required tokens from headers and use HandlerInterceptor to do the auth check. But for now, you have to use only Filters because your auth depends on request body.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom request filter that will check the request:

```
public class MyFilter implements OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        var user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        // do stuff you need to do here
        
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and then in your WebSecurityConfiguration class register the filter like this

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new MyFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() is returning null, if I do like this, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and perform your custom operations/filters on top of request by overriding `preHandle()` method.

Pseudocode is here:

```
@Component
public class SimpleInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        // Handle your request here. In your case, authentication check should go here.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Add the `SimpleInterceptor` to the registry to intercept the requests.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SimpleMvnConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    SimpleInterceptor simpleInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(simpleInterceptor);
    }
}
```

That's all!
EDIT 1:
To send the response from `preHandle` method, follow below pseudocode:

````
@Override                                                                                           
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    // Handle your request here. AIn your case, authentication check should go here.                
    if (!isValidAuth()) {                                                                           
        // Populate the response here.                                                              
        try {                                                                                       
            response.setStatus(401);                                                                
            response.getWriter().write("Authentication failed.");                                   
        } catch (IOException e) {                                                                   
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                    
        }                                                                                           
        return false;                                                                               
    }                                                                                               
    return true;                                                                                    
}                                                                                                   ```
````

Comment: How can I send 401 Http error response, if the authentication I do in preHandle fails?

Comment: Updated the response. Please check.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot read request body inside this. Since I need to check with one of the parameters inside request body Refer this link ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193380/get-requestbody-and-responsebody-at-handlerinterceptor.

Comment: How is your authentication sent? In the request body? I was hoping, normally auth tokens are sent via headers.

Comment: yes i get access to authenticated user through. String user=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(), but I need to verify one of the post body parameter with this user.

Comment: I also tried using filters and wanted to do the same. I got access to body in filter using ContentCachingRequestWrapper, but the problem lies in sending the error in that. When I do that, it says response already committed

Comment: I am confused where should I do this stuff, also tried using filters in spring security filter chain, but I keep getting anonymousUseror null in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() . For example, refer toucheqt's answer

Comment: Can you share the code on how you are doing it? Because filter is the right way to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Filter.

```
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    private void throwUnauthorized(ServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (!isValidAuth(request)) {
            throwUnauthorized(res);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    private boolean isValidAuth(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) {
    }

}
```

Register the filter using FilterRegistrationBean

```
@Bean                                                                                      
public FilterRegistrationBean<SimpleFilter> simpleFilter() {                               
    FilterRegistrationBean<SimpleFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new SimpleFilter());                                        
                                                                                           
    return registrationBean;                                                               
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: my class extends OncePerRequestFilter in the edit in question and I have overridden doFilterInternal method. does it matter , I mean is it different than Implementing Filter class ?

Comment: The issue is that I am not able to extract request body before calling do filter and I get the error : response has already been commited