Can not get request body in "Interceptor" layer of SpringBoot project
I'm trying to get request body of request and sending to database
Here is my lines of code :
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomInterceptor.class);
    private final LogStore logStore;

    public CustomInterceptor(LogStore logStore) {
        this.logStore = logStore;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // Wrap the request with ContentCachingRequestWrapper
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

        // Log request details
        Log requestLog = new Log();
        requestLog.setPath(wrappedRequest.getRequestURI());
        requestLog.setMethod(wrappedRequest.getMethod());
        String requestBody = getRequestBody(wrappedRequest);
        requestLog.setRequestObject(requestBody);

        // Save request log to database
        logStore.save(requestLog);

        return true; // Proceed with handler execution
    }

    private String getRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
        byte[] buf = request.getContentAsByteArray();
        if (buf.length > 0) {
            return new String(buf, 0, buf.length, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        return "";
    }
}

But I always get an empty request body,even though I send a Post method with a JSON request body,  what should I do to solve this problem ?
Thanks a lot

is preHandle getting called? Also please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216424/1752366

You have already consumed the body, this behaviour is expected. You need a Filter, not an Interceptor, in order pass the caching request wrapper to the next filter in the chain.

According to this thread: Get the POST request body from HttpServletRequest it is possible to get the requestBody like this:
String body =  request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
I tested this with your code and it should work.
Something seems to be wrong with your getRequestBody method or with the ContentCachingRequestWrapper that has certain conditions when to return the content.

I have tried the solution, but an exception is thrown with message : java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request

Could you please provide the stacktrace maybe?
